# How can I redirect to another component in react and pass the state that I set in the previous component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component I want to redirect to using react router. How can I set the state of the new component with a string that I chose on the original component? All of my redirects using react router are working and this component that is being redirected to isn't working. It is a html button when clicked should render this new components with initial data.

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const getProfile = async (member) => {
    console.log(member)
    props.history.push('/member', { user: member});
    console.log('----------- member------------')
  }

  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  return (
      <div>
        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>
    <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
        </tr>})}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Posts;
```

This is the component I am trying to redirect to on click.

```
const Member = (props)=> {  
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { state } = this.props.history.location;



  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  useEffect(async()=>{
    try {
     await setUser(state.user)
            console.log(user)
            console.log(user)

      const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });
      const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });


    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }, [])
```

I get the following error in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
Member
src/components/profiles/member.js:16
  13 | const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  14 | const [snInstance, setsnInstance] = useState({});
  15 | const [accounts, setsAccounts] = useState({});
> 16 | const { state } = this.props.history.location;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send some route state then the `push` method takes an object.

```
const getProfile = (member) => {
  console.log(member)
  props.history.push({
    pathname: '/member',
    state: {
      user: member,
    },
  });
  console.log('----------- member------------')
}
```

Additionally, `Member` is a functional component, so there is no `this`, just use the `props` object.

The route state is on the `location` prop, not the `history` object.

```
const Member = (props)=> {  
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { state } = props.location;

  // access state.user
```

Also additionally, `useEffect` callbacks can't be `async` as these imperatively return a Promise, interpreted as an effect cleanup function. You should declare an internal `async` function to invoke. On top of this, the `setuser` function ***isn't*** `async` so it can't be awaited on.

The following is what I think should be the effects for populating the `user` state and issuing side-effects:

```
// update user state when route state updates
useEffect(() => {
  if (state && state.user) {
    setUser(state.user);
  }
}, [state]);

// run effect when user state updates
useEffect(() => {
  const doEffects = async () => {
    try {
      const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });
      const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(state.user, { from: accounts[0] });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }

  doEffects();
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Thankyou. I tried this and it just keeps loading and the state isn't instantiated on the new component

Comment: @JohnBradshaw Right, I tried to call out that react state updates can't be awaited on. I've updated my answer with what I think are working effects for what you were trying to do previously.